# Merge multiple rows without overlapping data into one row SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data table with data like this:

| ID | Task | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jim | sleep | 5:50 |
| Jim | wakeup | 7:15 |
| Bob | sleep | 6:00 |
| Bob | brushteeth | 8:00 |
| Bob | eat | 9:00 |

and I am running a query to generate the following below

```
SELECT 
    dbo.Person.ID, 
    CAST(CASE WHEN dbo.DailyActivities.Activity = 'sleep' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) AS slept, 
    CAST(CASE WHEN dbo.DailyActivities.Activity = 'wakeup' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) AS wokeup, 
    CAST(CASE WHEN dbo.DailyActivities.Activity = 'brushteeth' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) AS brushedteeth, 
    CAST(CASE WHEN dbo.DailyActivities.Activity = 'eat' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) AS ate
FROM 
    dbo.Person 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.DailyActivities ON dbo.Person.ID = dbo.DailyActivities.ID
```

| ID | slept | wokeup | brushedteeth | ate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jim | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| Jim | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE |
| Bob | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| Bob | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE |
| Bob | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE |

How could we get the results for 1 ID per row like below

| ID | slept | wokeup | brushedteeth | ate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jim | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE |
| Bob | TRUE | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE |

Comment: Wrap a `MAX` around your `CASE` expressions.

Comment: Also, [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/) and should be avoided. You are far better off aliasing your objects in the `FROM` and using those to qualify your columns. This avoids the use of a feature that will be deprecated and possibly removed in a future version, and makes your code much more succinct and readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, use `MAX` around your `CASE` expressions; this is known as conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT P.ID, 
       CAST(MAX(CASE WHEN DA.Activity = 'sleep' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS bit) AS slept, 
       CAST(MAX(CASE WHEN DA.Activity = 'wakeup' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS bit) AS wokeup, 
       CAST(MAX(CASE WHEN DA.Activity = 'brushteeth' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS bit) AS brushedteeth, 
       CAST(MAX(CASE WHEN DA.Activity = 'eat' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS bit) AS ate
FROM dbo.Person P
     LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.DailyActivities DA ON P.ID = DA.ID
GROUP BY P.ID
```

Also, as I mentioned in the comments, I got rid of the 3+ part naming on the column as it [will be deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/).

Answer (score 1):

The easist way is use DISTINCT + Subqueries + CASE. I simplified your query a little bit so no join etc. so I have to type a little less. But i hope the concept behind it is clear.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    p.[ID]
  , CASE
      WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[Person] sub WHERE sub.[ID] = p.[ID] AND sub.[Task] = 'slept') > 0 THEN CAST(1 as bit)
      ELSE CAST(0 as bit)
    END AS [slept]
  , CASE
      WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[Person] sub WHERE sub.[ID] = p.[ID] AND sub.[Task] = 'wakeup') > 0 THEN CAST(1 as bit)
      ELSE CAST(0 as bit)
    END AS [wokeup]
  , CASE
      WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[Person] sub WHERE sub.[ID] = p.[ID] AND sub.[Task] = 'brushteeth') > 0 THEN CAST(1 as bit)
      ELSE CAST(0 as bit)
    END AS [brushteeth]
  , CASE
      WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[Person] sub WHERE sub.[ID] = p.[ID] AND sub.[Task] = 'eat') > 0 THEN CAST(1 as bit)
      ELSE CAST(0 as bit)
    END AS [ate]
FROM [dbo].[Person] p
```

Comment: this works, and you don't need the ```DISTINCT```

Comment: This'll be awfully inefficient, @Rick , don't do this. This will require **five** scans of the table `dbo.Person`, rather than one.

Comment: @Rick sorry but you need distinct or group by otherwise you get duplicate rows for each person

Comment: @Larnu I agree with you, every subquery accesses the tabel (or index) seperatly. But it's the "easiest" way

Comment: I disagree, @JohannesKrackowizer , aggregation is far easier.

Comment: @Larnu you are right i didn't thought of MAX(CASE...)